# Org. in Latex bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

How can I put this "(Org.)" (when there is an "organizer" of the articles in a book) in my references? I am trying to, but if I put it with the author's name, it understands as one of the middle names or as the last name. For example, if I put

```
author={Gadotti, Moacir (Org.)}
```

it generates "GADOTTI, M. O." in the bibliography. How can I generate "GADOTTI, M. (Org.)"?

Comment: Use an extra set of brackets, i.e., `author={{Gadotti, M. (Org.)}}`

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot!

Just for some more information: if I want it to show exactly "GADOTTI, M. (Org.)", I must write exactly like this. If I put extra brackets, it'll show exactly what I've written.

Comment: I noticed another problem: it works for the references, but when I cite it, instead of showing what it should, "GADOTTI, 1996", it shows what I put between the brackets, "GADOTTI, M. (Org.) , 1996". How can I fix it?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you use a BibTeX bibliography style that (a) truncates given names down to their initials and (b) generates authoryear-style citation call-outs. If that's the case, you can use the `\relax` method, shown below, to keep BibTeX from applying the truncation operation.

Without further information about the bibliography style that's in use, that's probably as far as one can go. Feel free to provide information about the bibliography style you're using.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{xyz,
   author= {Gadotti, Moacir {\relax (Org)}},
   title = {Thoughts},
   year  = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\citet{xyz}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't the person organising the stuff the editor?

Comment: @Johannes_B - Good question! I don't know for sure what the OP had in mind, but I assume it's a designation of the person who acted as the conference or event organizer. If that person is in fact the editor of the conference proceedings, then the `editor` field should definitely be used.

Comment: @Johannes_B, in Brazil, when someone organizes a book with articles about a subject, we use the reference as I've shown above.